# How to select the the row with the same name using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to use indexing to pull data from a panda dataframe. I ran into an issue I do not know how to solve.  The name of two of my rows are named the exact same way, but each row has it's own data.  Below is my line of code and it can be seen that  I put a row named basic in twice (because they have different dataframes), but each one has its own value:

```
i_s = i_s.loc[['Revenue','Cost of Revenue', 'Gross profit', 'Operating expenses', 'Total operating expenses', 'Operating income', 'Net income', 'Earnings per share', 'Basic', 'Weighted average shares outstanding', 'Basic', 'EBITDA']]
```

When I try to index using the code above, the dataframe with the row labeled basic comes up four times (two dataframes in total).  It selects each of the rows named basic and puts both dataframes where I call out basic in my .loc :

```
Revenue                                       0.0  1.059400e+10  9.789000e+09   
Cost of Revenue                               NaN           NaN           NaN   
Gross profit                                  2.0  6.420000e+09  5.691000e+09   
Operating expenses                            3.0  4.989000e+09  4.924000e+09   
Total operating expenses                      3.0  4.989000e+09  4.924000e+09   
Operating income                              8.0  1.431000e+09  7.670000e+08   
Net income                                   14.0  7.370000e+08  2.890000e+08   
Earnings per share                           16.0           NaN           NaN   
Basic                                        17.0  1.400000e+00  6.200000e-01   
Basic                                        20.0  5.254150e+08  5.145740e+08   
Weighted average shares outstanding          19.0           NaN           NaN   
Basic                                        17.0  1.400000e+00  6.200000e-01   
Basic                                        20.0  5.254150e+08  5.145740e+08   
EBITDA                                       22.0  1.838000e+09  1.150000e+09
```

For example:

```
    A    B   C
   foo   0   10
   foo   1   11
   foo   1   12
   foo   1   13
   foo   1   14
```

I would like to use .loc to call out the column 'A' by its label 'foo', however if I use df.loc['foo'], it will pull all 3.  I would like the output to only show some of them rather than all of them, like below:

```
    A    B   C
   foo   1   12
   foo   1   14
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? How do I select a row with the same name as another row using .loc?

Comment: Your example doesn't quite make sense. df.loc['foo'] generates an error. What's the logic to select row 2 and 4 only?

Comment: I am sorry that didn't make sense.  If you look at the dataframe above my simple example, the row 'Basic' shows up four times, duplicating itself twice.  I am indexing this dataframe by using .loc.  So I want all that information except the instances where the row 'Basic' Duplicates itself.  However, it is difficult for me because the first instance of the row 'Basic' is the row I want to keep and the last instance of the row 'Basic' I want to keep.  I want to discard the second and third instance of row 'Basic.'  But I need to be able to keep the order of Revenue, Cost of revenue, etc.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer below. Please check if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not the most phthonic way I wanted, the below should work.

Suppose you want to extract the rows with the index names:

```
rows = ['Revenue','Cost of Revenue', 'Gross profit', 'Operating expenses',
        'Total operating expenses', 'Operating income', 'Net income', 
        'Earnings per share', 'Basic', 'Weighted average shares outstanding', 
        'Basic', 'EBITDA']


# get the location index(es) for the rows you need in dict
loc_dict = {e: df.index.get_loc(e) for e in set(rows)}

# convert the row index(es) to a list
loc_dict = {k:[v] if isinstance(v,int) else np.where(v)[0].tolist() for k,v in loc_dict.items()}

# extract all the rows you need using iloc.
df.iloc[[loc_dict.get(e).pop(0) for e in rows]]
```

Note although you are using iloc here, it preserves the order of the rows as you specified in the rows list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.iloc` to get only the indices that you desire. Check out the docs to read more about [how to select data in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) and [the `iloc` attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3), columns=['a', 'a', 'b'])
```

To select the first of the two columns labeled 'a':

```
df.iloc[:, [0, 2]]
```

returns

```
   a  b
0  0  2
1  3  5
```

Comment: Yeah I know I can use it getting .iloc, however I would like to keep the dataframes I choose in that sequential order.  If I use .iloc I believe it changes the order I want.  I don't know if .loc can accomplish this though.  I have thought about using .drop_duplicates() and duplicated(), but can't it to work.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Would help if you made a simple dataframe example and posted your desired output for that example dataframe.

Comment: okay, I edited my question to include a brief example.  Does it make sense?